Changing a property value in JS, not rerending the HTML
I have a nested object array (finalData), for which I am using @track property.
Below is the JSON structure of first level of array (as it is huge I am pasting the first level)
[
   {
      "Name":"Oil Gas Salt Resources Act 1990",
      "Id":"a1S05000006zsNlEAI",
      "Question":"a1b05000005E1WJAA0",
      "Type":"Title",
      "Sections":[
         {
            "Display":true,
            "validateClass":"validate-block",
            "NotRequired":false,
            "Answer":"Not Answered Yet",
            "Name":"4(1) Obstruction of inspector",
            "Question":"a1b05000005E1WKAA0",
            "ParentQuestion":"a1b05000005E1WJAA0",
            "Type":"Section",
            "Id":"a1S05000006zsNmEAI",
            "totalQuestions":1,
            "totalAnswrdQuestions":0
         }            
      ],
      "totalQuestions":21,
      "totalAnswrdQuestions":1,
      "Display":true,
      "validateClass":"validate-block"
   }
]

When validate button is clicked in html, I am updating this array, by checking if the totalQuestions != totalAnswrdQuestions, then set the validateClass:"validate-block".
for(var i = 0; i < this.finalData.length; i++){
   let row = this.finalData[i];
   console.log('inside getAnswersByPage: handleUpdate:INCOMPLETE: row.totalQuestions==>', row.totalQuestions);
   console.log('inside getAnswersByPage: handleUpdate:INCOMPLETE: row.totalAnswrdQuestions==>', row.totalAnswrdQuestions);
   if(row.totalQuestions != row.totalAnswrdQuestions){
       let obj = {}
       obj.Name = row.Name;
       this.inCompleteSections.push(obj);
       row.validateClass = 'validate-block';
       if(row.Sections){
           for(var j = 0; j < row.Sections.length; j++){
               let secRec = row.Sections[j];
               if(secRec.totalQuestions != secRec.totalAnswrdQuestions){
                   secRec.validateClass = 'validate-block';

                   console.log('inside getAnswersByPage: handleUpdate:INCOMPLETE: secRec.validateClass==>', secRec.validateClass);
               }
               if(secRec.SubSections){
                   for(var k = 0; k < secRec.SubSections.length; k++){
                       let subsecRec = secRec.SubSections[k];
                       if(subsecRec.totalQuestions != subsecRec.totalAnswrdQuestions){
                           subsecRec.validateClass = 'validate-block';
                       }
                   }//end of subsections loop
               }
           }//end of sections for loop
       }//end of check for if sections exist
   }
}//end of title for loop

My sample HTML code:
<div class="collapse parent" for:each={finalData} for:item="title" key={title.Id}>
   <template lwc:if={title.Display}>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="titlelist"  onclick={changeToggle}> 
      <h4>
         {title.Name}  - &nbsp;
         <b class={title.validateClass}>
            {title.totalAnswrdQuestions}/{title.totalQuestions}
         </b>
      </h4>
   </template>
</div>

When I console.log finalData in JS, it is setting the validateClass property to validate-block, which is the class in css, to show the {title.totalAnswrdQuestions}/{title.totalQuestions} in red.
I could not figure why the html is not rerendered, even if I am changing the property of nested object array which is enabled with @track decorator.
Appreciate your help.
css:
.validate-block {
   color: #CD0000;
}


In the code you have added to your question, you're not actually updating the property that you are using to render the HTML. I'm not sure if this is just missing from the snippet, but you need to actually set the value of finalData as you're currently operating on a new variable and then not doing anything with it once you exit the loop.

Sometimes HTML is not able to parse the changes you are making directly in the tracked variable.
Workaround for this is store this.finalData in a local variable. Like below
let localFinalData = this.finalData;

Then do all the processing you want to do on localFinalData.
When you are done, overwrite finalData like below:
this.finalData = localFinalData;


Thanks for sharing your comments. I have tried that as well, but still it is not working
